# Apt stuck installing virtualbox guest additions

Tags: apt, virtualbox, dkms

I'm trying to run

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

but it hangs forever on a step

```
Loading new virtualbox-guest-5.2.10 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 4.15.0-23-generic
```

I have encountered this issue while trying to upgrade virtual box guest additions and cannot install it properly afterwards. How to deal with this issue or how to completely unistall/ignore it and make `apt-get` work correctly again

```
  $ uname -a
  Linux tapki 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 18:02:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and my Ubuntu version

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the system is waiting for a password on the background. In my case 3 times the password.

So when it seems to be stuck it is waiting just enter your password with enter for 3 or 4 times then it will continue the installation